# R convert raw data to character

Tags: r, mongodb, lapply, data-cleaning

I try to use R load data from mongodb with package "mongolite", and the code like this:

```
df <- db$find('{}', '{"CurrentId":1,"_id":0}')
```

Which I want to extract the `"CurrentId"` of collection, and variable `"CurrentId"` is ObjectId in mongodb, which may contains several ObjectId.

and the `df` look like this:

```
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
list()

[[4]]
list()

[[5]]
list()

[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] 56 cd 5f 02 b8 9b 5b d0 26 cb 39 c9

[[6]][[2]]
[1] 56 cd 6c 13 b8 9b 5b d0 26 cb 39 d5

[[6]][[3]]
[1] 56 cd 6f c6 b8 9b 5b d0 26 cb 39 de
```

And `df[[6]][[1]]`  is :

```
 [1] 56 cd 5f 02 b8 9b 5b d0 26 cb 39 c9
```

the type of `typeof(df[[6]][[1]])` is :

```
 [1] "raw"
```

I use `paste(dc3[[6]][[1]],collapse = '')` convert the raw type to string, just like mongodb ObjectId format:

```
 [1] "56cd5f02b89b5bd026cb39c9"
```

And then I try to convert all the raw data in `df` to `string` like above. So I use `sapply` function:

`sapply(df, function(x) paste(as.character(x),collapse = ''))`

and got this :

```
[1] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[2] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[3] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[4] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[5] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[6] "as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x5f, 0x02, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xc9))as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x6c, 0x13, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xd5))as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x6f, 0xc6, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xde))"
```

But I want to get something like this:

```
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
list()

[[4]]
list()

[[5]]
list()

[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
[1] "56cd5f02b89b5bd026cb39c9"

[[6]][[2]]
[1] "56cd6c13b89b5bd026cb39d5"

[[6]][[3]]
[1] "56cd6fc6b89b5bd026cb39de"
```

Could anyone know how to handle this? And could there be more efficient way to do the whole work?

**Update:**

I should give some code to reproduce my origin dataset:

```
test = as.raw(as.hexmode(x = c("56","cd","5f","02","b8","9b","5b","d0","26","cb","39","c9")))
df = lapply(1:10,function(x) test)
```

although this code produce this:

```
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 5f

[[2]][[2]]
[1] d0


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] 26

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 56


[[4]]
list()

[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
[1] cb


[[6]]
list()
```

It's not like original `df`, but I really don't know how to paste Raw data in nested list, hope this may help you!

the result of  `sapply(df, function(x) paste(x,collapse = ''))` is just like this:

```
[1] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[2] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[3] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[4] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[5] ""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[6] "as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x5f, 0x02, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xc9))as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x6c, 0x13, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xd5))as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x6f, 0xc6, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xde))"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `paste()` without calling `as.character()` within your `sapply()` call.
Short example:

```
convertRaw = function(x) paste(x,collapse = '') # works identical in sapply
test = as.raw(as.hexmode(x = c("56","cd","5f","02","b8","9b","5b","d0","26","cb","39","c9"))) # line copied from your sample
convertRaw(test)
[1] "56cd5f02b89b5bd026cb39c9"
```

**Update**
actually there is another issue that results from using a nested list. Because of you dealing with a nested list your sapply call needs to be nested too. You can i.e. call it via `lapply()`. Here is a short example hope that finally resolves your issue:

```
test = as.raw(as.hexmode(x = c("56","cd","5f","02","b8","9b","5b","d0","26","cb","39","c9")))
testList = list(list(),list(test,test)) # here I create a short nested list
res = lapply(testList,function(y) sapply(y,function(x) paste(x,collapse = '')))
print(res)
```

the result is:

```
[[1]] list() 

[[2]] [1] "56cd5f02b89b5bd026cb39c9" "56cd5f02b89b5bd026cb39c9"
```

if you prefer this:

```
[[1]] list()

[[2]] [[2]][[1]] 
[1] "56cd5f02b89b5bd026cb39c9"

[[2]][[2]] 
[1] "56cd5f02b89b5bd026cb39c9"
```

simply call, `lapply()` nested:

```
lapply(testList,function(y) lapply(y,function(x) paste(x,collapse = '')))
```

Comment: hi, David. I tried your solution but I still got the same result: "as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x5f, 0x02, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xc9))as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x6c, 0x13, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xd5))as.raw(c(0x56, 0xcd, 0x6f, 0xc6, 0xb8, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xd0, 0x26, 0xcb, 0x39, 0xde))"

Comment: you misread my suggestion. I've suggestion that instead of this: you'd enter

Comment: next comment as I can't edit anymore...
you misunderstood my solution. I've suggested that instead of this: 
`sapply(df, function(x) paste(as.character(x),collapse = ''))`
you'd enter this:
`sapply(df, function(x) paste(x,collapse = ''))`
The conversion `as.character()` returns you the strange result you don't want. Don't call it the conversion is innecessary!
in the second line of my answer I just read a sample and in the third line I call the actual function.

Comment: I tried, I think you're right with removing as.character, and your code works well for one line data, like "test = as.raw(as.hexmode(x = c("56","cd","5f","02","b8","9b","5b","d0","26","cb","39","c9")))", but I tried to apply this to a nested list, and it's not work, because no matter how many element in list, sapply alway paste it's all together, the result was just like i post in answer.

Comment: please provide an example including a nested list that starts with raw data so that I can reproduce your error

Comment: yes please accept the anwser so that others can see

Comment: sorry I'm late, and it's really a cool trick ! thank you David!